# method argument Array list variable's size is resetting back to zero after clear() and assigning new list value

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Below is the code in which I am getting an arraylist from which populating another temporary array

After first while loop , 2nd time onwards Stocks_TBCrawled is getting assigned correct value in if block but in for loop , the size is resetting back to zero.

Please let me know where am I going wrong in this logic ?

```
public void doConnectCall(List<String> Stocks_TBCrawled){
    try{                 
        timeOutRequests = new ArrayList<String>();              
        int retryCount = 0;
        while(retryCount < 3){        
            if(retryCount != 0 ){
                   Stocks_TBCrawled.clear();
                   Stocks_TBCrawled  =  timeOutRequests; 
                   timeOutRequests.clear();
            }
            for(int listCounter = 0;  listCounter < Stocks_TBCrawled.size();   listCounter++ ){    
                try{
                     mfCount = 0;
                     doc = Jsoup.connect("http:xxx ).timeout(3000).get();
                }catch(Exception e){                                                                                                                      
                    timeOutRequests.add(Stocks_TBCrawled.get(listCounter));          
                    continue;
                }
            }                                                                                                                                                           
            retryCount++;                                      
        }                                         
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following lines of code assign the object `timeOutRequests` to the reference `Stocks_TBCrawled`. Now, both `Stocks_TBCrawled` and `timeOutRequests` point to the same list.

```
Stocks_TBCrawled  =  timeOutRequests; 
timeOutRequests.clear();
```

So, when you do call `timeOutRequests.clear();` method, the list object to which both `Stocks_TBCrawled` and `timeOutRequests` point is cleared.

To correctly solve this issue, use the `List.addAll(..)` method to achieve what you need.

In your case this would become:

```
Stocks_TBCrawled.addAll(timeOutRequests);
timeOutRequests.clear();
```

Hope this helps!